# Parsing XML in python and deletion of containers

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, autosar

I'm trying to write a Python script that will go through the file and remove the container of a particular node attribute. For instance, my tree looks like:

```
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/ComIPduCancellationSupport</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/xyz</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/ComIPduCancellationSupport</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/xyz</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/ComIPduCancellationSupport</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
</collection>
```

**Q1**

The whole container  should be removed if the attribute of the child node `<DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">` equals : `/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/ComIPduCancellationSupport`

The script I have written is :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('autosar1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.findall(".//ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE"):
    for z in child.findall(".//DEFINITION-REF[@DEST='ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF']"):
        if z.text == "/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/ComIPduCancellationSupport":
            child.remove(z)         
tree.write('output.xml')
```

But I am not getting the intended results.
The result I am getting is:

```
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
<ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
<SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
</ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>

<ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
<SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
</ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>

<ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
<SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
</ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>

<ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
<SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
</ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>

<ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
<SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
</ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
</collection>
```

The result I want to get :

```
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/xyz</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
  <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
    <SHORT-NAME>RTE_ABC</SHORT-NAME>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-BOOLEAN-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/xyz</DEFINITION-REF>
  </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE>
</collection>
```

**Q2**

Instead of hardcoding the node attribute in the `if` condition, is it possible that by taking user input (in command prompt maybe),suppose as `"ComIPduCancellationSupport"`, (not the whole attribute as `"/AUTOSAR/EcucDefs/Com/ComConfig/ComIPdu/ComIPduCancellationSupport"`),the desired output is achieved.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you use third-party modules like `lxml`?

Comment: No, I did nt use any 3rd party apps

Comment: Can you use `lxml`?

Comment: I don't have an idea about lxml.Can you tell me how it will help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the third-party, [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html), *the most feature-rich and easy-to-use library for processing XML and HTML in the Python language*. You can install with pip or [binary file](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Windows. The reason for recommendation is the module can run full W3C conformant XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0 where the latter XSLT is useful for you.

[XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special-purpose language that can transform XML files like removing nodes conditionally. Specifically in XSLT, we run the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) (to copy entire document as is) and then run an empty template on the node we intend to remove. Notice the use of [`contains()`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_contains.html) to check for a string anywhere in the text of that node. No `for` loop or `if` logic needed for this approach.

And with Python's lxml we can build a dynamic XSLT script (which by the way *is* an XML file) from string and pass a string such as *COMPU-METHOD-REF* into `contains()`. Such a string can derive from user input. Notice the `{0}` placeholder for string `.format()`.

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et
doc = et.parse('Input.xml')

xsl_str='''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                         xmlns:doc="http://autosar.org/3.0.2">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE -->
  <xsl:template match="INTEGER-TYPE[descendant::COMPU-METHOD-REF/@DEST='COMPU-METHOD' and 
                                    contains(descendant::COMPU-METHOD-REF, '{0}')]">    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>'''

# LOAD DYNAMIC XSL STRING (PASSING BELOW STRING INTO ABOVE)
xsl = et.fromstring(xsl_str.format('CoolantTemp_T'))

transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(doc)

# OUTPUT TO SCREEN
print(result)    
# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TOP-LEVEL-PACKAGES>
  <AR-PACKAGE>
    <SHORT-NAME>DataType</SHORT-NAME>
    <ELEMENTS>
      <INTEGER-TYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>EngineSpeed_T</SHORT-NAME>
        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
          <COMPU-METHOD-REF DEST="COMPU-METHOD">/DataType/DataTypeSemantics/EngineSpeed_T</COMPU-METHOD-REF>
        </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
        <LOWER-LIMIT INTERVAL-TYPE="CLOSED">0</LOWER-LIMIT>
        <UPPER-LIMIT INTERVAL-TYPE="CLOSED">65535</UPPER-LIMIT>
      </INTEGER-TYPE>
      <INTEGER-TYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>VehicleSpeed_T</SHORT-NAME>
        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
          <COMPU-METHOD-REF DEST="COMPU-METHOD">/DataType/DataTypeSemantics/VehicleSpeed_T</COMPU-METHOD-REF>
        </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
        <LOWER-LIMIT INTERVAL-TYPE="CLOSED">0</LOWER-LIMIT>
        <UPPER-LIMIT INTERVAL-TYPE="CLOSED">65535</UPPER-LIMIT>
      </INTEGER-TYPE>
      <INTEGER-TYPE>
        <SHORT-NAME>Percent_T</SHORT-NAME>
        <SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
          <COMPU-METHOD-REF DEST="COMPU-METHOD">/DataType/DataTypeSemantics/Percent_T</COMPU-METHOD-REF>
        </SW-DATA-DEF-PROPS>
        <LOWER-LIMIT INTERVAL-TYPE="CLOSED">0</LOWER-LIMIT>
        <UPPER-LIMIT INTERVAL-TYPE="CLOSED">255</UPPER-LIMIT>
      </INTEGER-TYPE>
    </ELEMENTS>
    <SUB-PACKAGES>
      <AR-PACKAGE>
        <SHORT-NAME>DataTypeSemantics</SHORT-NAME>
        <ELEMENTS>
          <COMPU-METHOD>
            <SHORT-NAME>EngineSpeed_T</SHORT-NAME>
            <UNIT-REF DEST="UNIT">/DataType/DataTypeUnits/rpm</UNIT-REF>
            <COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
              <COMPU-SCALES>
                <COMPU-SCALE>
                  <COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                    <COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                      <V>0</V>
                      <V>1</V>
                    </COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                    <COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                      <V>8</V>
                    </COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                  </COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                </COMPU-SCALE>
              </COMPU-SCALES>
            </COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
          </COMPU-METHOD>
          <COMPU-METHOD>
            <SHORT-NAME>VehicleSpeed_T</SHORT-NAME>
            <UNIT-REF DEST="UNIT">/DataType/DataTypeUnits/kph</UNIT-REF>
            <COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
              <COMPU-SCALES>
                <COMPU-SCALE>
                  <COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                    <COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                      <V>0</V>
                      <V>1</V>
                    </COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                    <COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                      <V>64</V>
                    </COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                  </COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                </COMPU-SCALE>
              </COMPU-SCALES>
            </COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
          </COMPU-METHOD>
          <COMPU-METHOD>
            <SHORT-NAME>Percent_T</SHORT-NAME>
            <UNIT-REF DEST="UNIT">/DataType/DataTypeUnits/Percent</UNIT-REF>
            <COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
              <COMPU-SCALES>
                <COMPU-SCALE>
                  <COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                    <COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                      <V>0</V>
                      <V>0.4</V>
                    </COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                    <COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                      <V>1</V>
                    </COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                  </COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                </COMPU-SCALE>
              </COMPU-SCALES>
            </COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
          </COMPU-METHOD>
          <COMPU-METHOD>
            <SHORT-NAME>CoolantTemp_T</SHORT-NAME>
            <UNIT-REF DEST="UNIT">/DataType/DataTypeUnits/DegreeC</UNIT-REF>
            <COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
              <COMPU-SCALES>
                <COMPU-SCALE>
                  <COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                    <COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                      <V>-40</V>
                      <V>1</V>
                    </COMPU-NUMERATOR>
                    <COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                      <V>2</V>
                    </COMPU-DENOMINATOR>
                  </COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS>
                </COMPU-SCALE>
              </COMPU-SCALES>
            </COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS>
          </COMPU-METHOD>
        </ELEMENTS>
      </AR-PACKAGE>
      <AR-PACKAGE>
        <SHORT-NAME>DataTypeUnits</SHORT-NAME>
        <ELEMENTS>
          <UNIT>
            <SHORT-NAME>rpm</SHORT-NAME>
            <DISPLAY-NAME>rpm</DISPLAY-NAME>
          </UNIT>
          <UNIT>
            <SHORT-NAME>kph</SHORT-NAME>
            <DISPLAY-NAME>kph</DISPLAY-NAME>
          </UNIT>
          <UNIT>
            <SHORT-NAME>Percent</SHORT-NAME>
            <DISPLAY-NAME>Percent</DISPLAY-NAME>
          </UNIT>
          <UNIT>
            <SHORT-NAME>DegreeC</SHORT-NAME>
            <DISPLAY-NAME>DegreeC</DISPLAY-NAME>
          </UNIT>
        </ELEMENTS>
      </AR-PACKAGE>
    </SUB-PACKAGES>
  </AR-PACKAGE>
</TOP-LEVEL-PACKAGES>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I am getting an error.I tried to install the file lxml‑4.0.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl from the link you had mentioned.I got the following message in the command prompt:Requirement already satisfied: lxml==4.0.0 from  file */lxml-4.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl in c:*\python\python35\lib\site-packages. When I run the python script I am getting the following error:AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'XSLT'

Comment: You did not import the correct etree. Remove the built-in module `import xml.etree.ElementTree` and only use lxml: `import lxml.etree as et`.

Comment: That was the error.It is working now.Thanks a. lot.But I tried your solution on another input file.I made some changes in your script.There is no changes in the output file at all.Can you please have a look?Here's the link of input file and script: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxt5bddXF4ctYUxKWDh5amRmOTA

Comment: Unlike this simplified example. The other XML has [default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#defaulting), where in root there is an *xmlns* without a colon-separated name. This changes the setup somewhat. Often I advise posters to always include good example of their XML with *all* namespaces.

Comment: I deleted the <AUTOSAR> container which has that xmlns  and ran the script still no change in the output.

Comment: See update. Your xpath was not accurate since the text you search is not a direct child to `INTEGER-TYPE` like your simple XML assumed. Use `descendant::*`. And no need to delete root. XSLT now defines the default namespace with a prefix,*doc*, (entirely chosen by me) in its root. Note: source XML is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yeah man,this time it worked.Thanks a lot buddy. धन्यवादः महोदय ।